# How do I iterate over each line in a file with Bash?

Tags: bash, loops, iteration

Given a text file with multiple lines, I would like to iterate over each line in a Bash script. I had attempted to use `cut`, but `cut` does not accept `\n` (newline) as a delimiter.

This is an example of the file I am working with:

```
one
two 
three 
four
```

Does anyone know how I can loop through each line of this text file in Bash?

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939038/how-do-you-run-a-command-eg-chmod-for-each-line-of-a-file/ also has relevant answers

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `cat` for concatenating or displaying. No need for it here.

```sh
file="/path/to/file"
while read line; do
  echo "${line}"
done < "${file}"
```

Comment: I'd agree with this, but this is noticably slower than the `cut` approach.

Comment: @StanStrum This solution should be much quicker (`O(n)` time complexity) and more readable than the `cut` approach. The OP was asking how to iterate over every single line in a file. Using `cut`, one would have to either know the number of lines in the file and write that many statements using `cut` or write a while loop anyway giving you an `O(n + n²)` time complexity.

Comment: This solution is, however, not complete as there are some pitfalls and edge cases that would come up.

Answer (score 89):

I found myself in the same problem, this works for me:

```
cat file.cut | cut -d$'\n' -f1
```

Or:

```
cut -d$'\n' -f1 file.cut
```

Comment: why does this work? what does the dollar sign do in this case

Comment: @JulesG.M. it works because Bash has a feature called ANSI-C Quoting. The documentation mentions this: "Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.". You can find the docs here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

Answer (score 4):

```
cat FILE|while read line; do # 'line' is the variable name
   echo "$line" # do something here
done
```

or (see comment):

```
while read line; do # 'line' is the variable name
   echo "$line" # do something here
done < FILE
```

Comment: [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) - use `while ... done < file`

Comment: It's not useless, it's perhaps wasteful (after reading this paragraph), but it's also more readable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use:

```
echo -n `cut ...`
```

This suppresses the \n at the end

Answer (score 2):

So, some really good (possibly better) answers have been provided already. But looking at the phrasing of the original question, in wanting to use a BASH for-loop, it amazed me that nobody mentioned a solution with change of Field Separator IFS. It's a pure bash solution, just like the accepted read line

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS='\n'
for field in $(<filename)
do your_thing;
done
IFS=$old_IFS
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the output will always be newline-delimited, use `head -n 1` in lieu of `cut -f1` (note that you mentioned a for loop in a script and your question was ultimately not script-related).

Many of the other answers, including the accepted one, have multiple lines unnecessarily. No need to do this over multiple lines or changing the default delimiter on the system.

Also, the solution provided by Ivan with `-d$'\n'` did not work for me either on Mac OSX or CentOS 7. Since his answer is four years old, I assume something must have changed on the logic of the `$` character for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

## While loop with input redirection and `read` command.

You should not be using `cut` to perform a sequential iteration of each line in a file as `cut` was not designed to do this.

> Print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.
> — [`man cut`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/cut.1.html)

### TL;DR

You should use a **while loop with the `read -r` command and redirect standard input to your file** inside a function scope where `IFS` is set to `\n` and use `-E` when using `echo`.

```sh
processFile() {          # Function scope to prevent overwriting IFS globally
  file="$1"              # Any file that exists
  local IFS="\n"         # Allows spaces and tabs
  while read -r line; do # Read exits with 1 when done; -r allows \
    echo -E "$line"      # -E allows printing of \ instead of gibberish
  done < $file           # Input redirection allows us to read file from stdin
}
processFile /path/to/file
```

---

### Iteration

In order to iterate over each line of a file, we can use a while loop. This will let us iterate as many times as we need to.

```sh
while <condition>; do
  <body>
done
```

### Getting our file ready to read

We can use the [`read`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/read.1posix.html) command to store a single line from standard input in a variable. Before we can use that to read a line from our file, we need to redirect standard input to point to our file. We can do this with input redirection. According to the [man pages for bash](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/bash.1.html#redirection), the syntax for redirection is `[fd]<file` where `fd` defaults to standard input (a.k.a file descriptor `0`). We can place this before or after our while loop.

```sh
while <condition>; do
  <body>
done < /path/to/file

# or the non-traditional way
</path/to/file while <condition>; do
  <body>
done
```

### Reading the file and ending the loop

Now that our file can be read from standard input, we can use `read`. The syntax for `read` in our context is `read [-r] var...` where `-r` preserves the `\` (backslash) character, instead of using it as an escape sequence character, and `var` is the name of the variable to store the input in. You can have multiple variables to store pieces of the input in but we only need one to read an entire line. Along with this, to preserve any backslashes in any output from `echo` you will likely need to use the `-E` flag to disable the interpretation of backslash escapes. If you have any indentation (spaces or tabs), you will need to temporarily change the `IFS` (Input Field Separators) variable to only `"\n"`; normally it is set to `" \t\n"`.

```sh
main() {
  local IFS="\n"
  read -r line
  echo -E "$line"
}

main
```

#### How do we use `read` to end our while loop?

There is really only one reliable way, that I know of, to determine when you've finished reading a file with `read`: check the exit value of `read`. If the exit value of `read` is `0` then we successfully read a line, if it is `1` or higher then we reached EOF (end of file). With that in mind, we can place the call to `read` in our while loop's condition section.

```sh
processFile() {
  # Could be any file you want hardcoded or dynamic
  file="$1"

  local IFS="\n"
  while read -r line; do
    # Process line here
    echo -E "$line"
  done < $file
}

processFile /path/to/file1
processFile /path/to/file2
```

[A visual breakdown of the above code via Explain Shell.](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=processFile%28%29+%7B+file%3D%22%241%22%3B+local+IFS%3D%22%5Cn%22%3B+while+read+-r+line%3B+do+echo+-E+%22%24line%22%3B+done+%3C+%24file%3B+%7D%3B+processFile+%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile1%3B)

Answer (score 0):

If I am executing a command and want to cut the output but it has multiple lines I found it helpful to do

```
echo $([command]) | cut [....]
```

This puts all the output of `[command]` on a single line that can be easier to process.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to iterate the records in a file would be the following via `for` loop in `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Showing the records in the file';
for i in `cat myfile.txt`; do echo $i; done;  # this will show records line by line
echo 'End of the script';
```

Answer (score -2):

My opinion is that "cut" uses '\n' as its default delimiter.
If you want to use cut, I have two ways:

```
    cut -d^M -f1 file_cut
```

I make ^M By click Enter After Ctrl+V. Another way is

```
    cut -c 1- file_cut
```

Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above worked for me (bash,version 4.2.45).

Comment: `cut` does not use '\n' as its default delimiter.