# Pass contents of LaTeX statement to command

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I can extract the contents of all the `\include` statements from a latex file (and append ".tex" to each one) with

```
grep -P "\\\\include{" Thesis_master.tex |sed -n -e"s/\\\\include{/$1/" -e" s/}.*$/.tex/p"
```

(I couldn't get lookbehinds working in `grep`, hence the pipe through `sed`.  That gives me a list of filenames, one per line.  I'd now like to pass those files to `aspell`.  But `aspell` only accepts one filename as an argument, so I can't just tack `|xargs aspell -c` on the end.

I've read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13939038/2583476) but that reads from a *file* line by line through `xargs`.  So how do I get it to read from the output of `sed` line by line?

Comment: If you show your input data then probably we can suggest lookbehind also

Comment: @anubhava, thank you: a sample line is `\include{chap_theory/chap_theory}%` I think the opening `{` was causing much of the trouble - should I or shouldn't I escape it and if so how?  I tried quite a few things before just piping through sed - which I'd need to do to append the ".tex" I think

Comment: For lookbehind, use `grep -P` with perl regular expression. (assuming GNU grep)

Comment: @glennjackman thank you, I think I did but now can't find those attempts in my command history to check - I was probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: So the lookbehind works now but of course `grep` (by default) prints the whole line.

Comment: Then add `-o` option to grep, that only outputs the matched text

Comment: Try `xargs -n1` ... and `man xargs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `xargs -L 1` should do what you need:

```
grep -P "\\\\include{" Thesis_master.tex | \
sed -n -e"s/\\\\include{/$1/" -e" s/}.*$/.tex/p" | \
xargs -L 1 aspell -c
```

<sub>*(Backslash line continuation added for readability)*</sub>

This will cause `xargs` to call `aspell` exactly once per line from the `sed` pipe.

---

Since your `aspell` commands appear to exit with a 255 code, this causes `xargs` to stop.  You could trick xargs into not exiting by doing something like:

```
grep -P "\\\\include{" Thesis_master.tex | \
sed -n -e"s/\\\\include{/$1/" -e" s/}.*$/.tex/p" | \
xargs -L 1 -I % bash -c "aspell -c %; true"
```

This will run `aspell` in a subshell, followed by the `true` command which always return a 0 exit code to xargs.

Comment: I believe you're right - now trying to fix an issue with aspell closing with exit code 255 and no error message!

Comment: You can debug `xargs` commands by changing your command to something like `xargs -L 1 echo aspell -c`.  That way, xargs will effectively simply echo every command instead of executing it.  You can then run the echoed commands manually and figure out why they're failing.

Comment: I was just trying that -- thanks -- I get `aspell -c chap_Theory/chap_Theory.tex` etc.  Which works if I copy and paste or retype but not from xargs.  Equally if I redirect the output of sed in my Q to a file tmp.txt, strip that to one line, and `cat tmp.txt | xargs aspell -c` it gives the same behaviour - I think I might have aspell related digging to do.

Comment: From the `xargs` manpage: "The xargs utility exits immediately (without processing any further input) if [...], or an invocation of utility exits with a value of 255."

Comment: @ChrisH See my edit for a possible way to prevent xargs from quitting early

Comment: That didn't work either it echoes what I'd expect but with the echo taken out it gives me back the input line straight away, with some disk activity - I never see the aspell screen.  But if I run `grep -P "\\\\include{" Thesis_master.tex |sed -n -e"s/\\\\include{//" -e" s/}.*$/.tex/p" |xargs -t -L 1 -I%  xterm -e "aspell -c %; true"` (-t for debug) it works, just with aspell in an xterm window.  Strange but I have something tat runs for now so thank you for all your help.

Comment: @ChrisH Oops, I should have taken that `echo` out.  Edited.

Comment: I thought it was there for debugging! But I think aspell is fussy about screen or I/O or something - calling xterm as in my previous comment turns out not to need the `; true`.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` recipe is:

```
grep -oP '\\include{\K.+?(?=})' latex.file | xargs aspell ...
```

Comment: `\K` was new to me - it seems much easier than lookbehind where it does the job.

Comment: Especially when you need variable width lookbehind, which `(?<=` does not allow