# Is bash a programming language?

Tags: bash

**TL;DR;** What are shell scripts? Is it a programming language / is there a programming language we use in shell scripts?

---

**disclaimer**: a bit offtopic
So bash stands for *Bourne-again shell*. A (Unix) Shell is a command line user interface or maybe one could call it an interpreter (?)

So I'm filling out an application for a new job and you get asked for experience of different programming languages and then there is this box at the bottom *other experiences* - I started typing *python 2.7, powershell, bas...* Wait! bash isn't a programming language - it's a console that can execute shell scripts... so... eh.... oh my god I have no idea!

Comment: FWIW, please **do** include Bash as a programming language skill if you have it. After all, [scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) _are_ programming languages. Technically however, if you know enough scripting languages, you could list them separately if the document permits. After having had over a dozen Linux-based job interviews over the years, not one interviewer has asked me why I listed Bash as a programming language. If anything, they also wanted to see sed and awk in that list.

Comment: Not only a programming language, but **the best** programming language for many things. Those things that can be done simpler by calling other programs, and composing them. **Huge** time saver. Just make sure to keep the code broken into the smallest functions, otherwise it gets obscure to understand and test.

Comment: Yes, in the same way a rock is a hammer.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

We can say that **yes**, it is a programming language.

According to `man bash`, Bash is a "sh-compatible command language". Then, we can say a "command language" is "a programming language through which a user communicates with the operating system or an application".

From `man bash`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> **Bash is an sh-compatible command language** interpreter that executes commands read from the standard input or from a file. Bash
>   also incorporates useful features from the Korn and C shells (ksh and
>   csh).

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/

> Bash is the GNU Project's shell. Bash is the Bourne Again SHell. Bash
>   is an sh-compatible shell that incorporates useful features from the
>   Korn shell (ksh) and C shell (csh). It is intended to conform to the
>   IEEE POSIX P1003.2/ISO 9945.2 Shell and Tools standard. It offers
>   functional improvements over sh for both programming and interactive
>   use. In addition, most sh scripts can be run by Bash without
>   modification.

And a UNIX shell is... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell

> A Unix shell is a command-line interpreter or shell that provides a
>   traditional user interface for the Unix operating system and for
>   Unix-like systems. Users direct the operation of the computer by
>   entering commands as text for a command line interpreter to execute,
>   or by creating text scripts of one or more such commands. Users
>   typically interact with a Unix shell using a terminal emulator,
>   however, direct operation via serial hardware connections, or
>   networking session, are common for server systems.

Comment: So bash is a language - but it is also a shell.. ? This is confusing, isn't it?

Comment: @Brettetete you can also start Python in interactive mode and it behaves like a shell. Or JavaScript, or Ruby or any script language.

Comment: @Zeeker ohhhh... the penny has dropped. That makes a lot of sense

Comment: @Brettetete regarding your final goal, I would definitely write "bash" in your cv. I do it, also with "awk".

Comment: The bit you left off the first quote (emphasis mine): "It offers functional improvements over sh for both *programming* and interactive use."

Comment: @PaulEvans you are right. I amended my answer with a broad view after reading more stuff. So it is indeed a programming language with which we interact with the OS.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I've posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67498861/1765658), where I give my opinion about `command == programming`...

Answer (score 29):

Bash most certainly *is* a programming language, one that specialises in the unix/linux shell scripting.  It's turing complete so you could (theoretically) write any program in Bash.

Comment: Agreed - it is all semantics that resolve around how you define programming language. Does it have specializes syntax, data handling/structures, test constructs, I/O routines, etc...

Comment: Qualified in the "it is all semantics that resolve around how you define programming language" Yes it is a shell, but associated with that shell is a set of rules and syntax that allow you to interact with the shell. `man bash` contains most. So, yes it is a shell, and yes it is a programming language designed to allow interaction with that shell.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So if i write a simple program in C(which allows you to write loops/ifthens,write to files and store variables) then it is a programming language ?

Comment: It's not worth this perfunctory level of debate. The question was will I get in trouble listing BASH as a programming language skill on a job application. If the employer wants to delve into the semantics that's fine, but I don't think any employer could ding you for listing it. In answer to your comment - sure -- how do you think all the c-like languages began.

Comment: It's also not that hard to write proper "programs" in bash. Kubernetes and git both use large amounts of bash for example. I personally have solved regular whiteboarding problems in bash as welll..

Answer (score 16):

There is no perfect definition of what a programming language really is but you can say that every language that is [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) is a programming language in the sense of that every thinkable program can theoretically be written in it (even if it may be awkward to do so and even if it would be horribly slow to run). And Bash is Turing-complete, so there is nothing that could not be programmed in Bash.

The problem with Bash, shells in general is, that it lacks a lot of base functionality, thus when writing scripts for them, you often in fact call external programs to perform the desired work. But that's only taking a shortcut. E.g. if you'd need floating point functionality in a shell, you could actually implement it. It would be possible to write a full IEEE 754 standard implementation in everything that is Turing-complete. In practice such an implementation would be huge, require tons of memory and be horribly slow, so one better calls `bc` for that. But even implementing `bc` entirely in bash would be possible.

Here's a bash script I've once written that draws a Mandelbrot set to console. You better be prepared to get some cups of coffee if you want to see the final result, it's going to be a very long night:

```
#!/bin/bash

BAILOUT=16
MAX_ITERATIONS=1000

function iterate {
    # $1 is x
    # $2 is y
    local zi=0
    local zr=0
    local i=0

    local cr
    cr=$(printf "%s\n" "scale=16; $2 - 0.5" | bc)

    while true
    do
        local temp
        local zr2
        local zi2
        i=$((i + 1))
        zr2=$(printf "%s\n" "scale=16; ($zr * $zr) - ($zi * $zi) + $cr" | bc)
        zi2=$(printf "%s\n" "scale=16; (($zr * $zi) * 2) + $1" | bc)
        temp=$(printf "%s\n" "(($zi * $zi) + ($zr * $zr)) > $BAILOUT" | bc)

        if ((temp == 1))
        then
            return "$i"
        fi

        if ((i > MAX_ITERATIONS))
        then
            return 0
        fi

        zr="$zr2"
        zi="$zi2"
    done
}

function mandelbrot {
    local y
    for ((y = -39; y < 39; y++))
    do
        printf "\n"
        local x
        for ((x = -39; x < 39; x++))
        do
            local xi
            local yi
            local ires
            xi=$(printf "%s\n" "scale=16; $x / 40.0" | bc)
            yi=$(printf "%s\n" "scale=16; $y / 40.0" | bc)
            iterate "$xi" "$yi"
            ires=$?

            if ((ires == 0))
            then
                printf "*"
            else
                printf " "
            fi
        done
    done
    printf "\n"
}

mandelbrot
```

For those who cannot wait that long, the result should look like this:

```
                                       *                                      
                                       *                                      
                                       *                                      
                                       *                                      
                                       *                                      
                                      ***                                     
                                     *****                                    
                                     *****                                    
                                      ***                                     
                                       *                                      
                                   *********                                  
                                 *************                                
                                ***************                               
                             *********************                            
                             *********************                            
                              *******************                             
                              *******************                             
                              *******************                             
                              *******************                             
                            ***********************                           
                              *******************                             
                              *******************                             
                             *********************                            
                              *******************                             
                              *******************                             
                               *****************                              
                                ***************                               
                                 *************                                
                                   *********                                  
                                       *                                      
                                ***************                               
                            ***********************                           
                         * ************************* *                        
                         *****************************                        
                      * ******************************* *                     
                       *********************************                      
                      ***********************************                     
                    ***************************************                   
               *** ***************************************** ***              
               *************************************************              
                ***********************************************               
                 *********************************************                
                 *********************************************                
                ***********************************************               
                ***********************************************               
              ***************************************************             
               *************************************************              
               *************************************************              
              ***************************************************             
              ***************************************************             
         *    ***************************************************    *        
       *****  ***************************************************  *****      
       ****** *************************************************** ******      
      ******* *************************************************** *******     
    ***********************************************************************   
    ********* *************************************************** *********   
       ****** *************************************************** ******      
       *****  ***************************************************  *****      
              ***************************************************             
              ***************************************************             
              ***************************************************             
              ***************************************************             
               *************************************************              
               *************************************************              
              ***************************************************             
                ***********************************************               
                ***********************************************               
                  *******************************************                 
                   *****************************************                  
                 *********************************************                
                **** ****************** ****************** ****               
                 ***  ****************   ****************  ***                
                  *    **************     **************    *                 
                         ***********       ***********                        
                         **  *****           *****  **                        
                          *   *                 *   *
```

It shall resemble this kind of thing turned by 90 degree (and a bit squeezed):

[image: Mandelbrot set]

Comment: From 1 night to less than 10'! Avoiding *forks*, running `bc` as background subtask... Try [my modified version of bash mandelbrot](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mandelbrot_backgndBc.sh.txt) (Still ugly, but quicker! ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri Very clever optimization but doesn't work on macOS. Fails with `line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `<'`. Note that macOS only ships 3.2.57 and never will ship bash 4 as the licensing was changed.

Comment: Ok, there is [a modified version tested under MacOS and bash 3.2.57](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mandelbrot_backgndBc_4macOs.sh.txt) (Execution time: 8m33.022s)

Comment: @F.Hauri No need for bashisms here. A POSIX shell version is even slightly faster [POSIX/shell Mandelbrot @ Gist-GitHub](https://gist.github.com/leagris/59e1b7e72462024b278652696f375e71)

Comment: @LéaGris You're right about bashism, but the way you address fifos is something wrong. you could gain some seconds by using `<&9` in your code. Try: [mandelbrot_posix.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mandelbrot_posix.sh.txt)

Comment: @F.Hauri updated the Gist with your fixes and made it more visually appealing with a shade of grey and some optimizations

Comment: @LéaGris forks to `tput` could be limited too! see [my answer about tput setaf...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521120/27653)

Comment: @LéaGris  One of the advantage using bc as background is: you could define and use function in bc! Now [my new version](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mandelbrot_posix-func2bc.sh.txt) make the job in less than 10 seconds!!

Comment: @F.Hauri could not stream tput with POSIX shell but used your bc function and now render same orientation and colour gradient as reference picture above https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY17L.jpg

Comment: @LéaGris regarding all this, I've posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67498861/1765658), where you've been cited

Comment: @LéaGris, Posted today a [bash script for parsing log files against time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41831934/1765658) working as a *super-language*. Feel free to build a POSIX version! (If not quicker, they will be more portable!)

Answer (score 7):

### My two cents

Coming to this SO question somewhat late, reading [fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28693815/1765658), I think *"programming language"* is not exactly same thing as *"command language"*, meaning a language intended to *run commands*.

About *Turing* consideration, yes, you could... I personally wrote a lot of *libraries* around [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (around monitoring, backups, sysadmin, networking, etc.), but clearly for writing a *program*,
you have to use a *real programming language*.

### However

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is a ***shell*** (like [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) and others [shell](/questions/tagged/shell))! Meaning an **overall aggregator language**, or a **super language**.

First goal is to be an *interactive* command processor,
in order to use and maintain [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) systems.

One of its first applications was to create [wrapper](/questions/tagged/wrapper)s in order to prepare an *environment* for running programs written in other languages.

So this *command processor* is
ideal for systems, filesystems, networks and a lot of *administration* tasks, because
it's interactive and using its history makes the job of *creating scripts* just easy.

### Its real power

As this language is intended to deal with [io](/questions/tagged/io)s, [fork](/questions/tagged/fork)s, [fifo](/questions/tagged/fifo)s and because [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) said [*everything is a file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) script could normally deal with *everything*, directly or by using *other* tools/binaries/applications. This language is intended to
create condition, execution groups and interaction around *everything*.

This could open a lot of interactivity between systems, networks, iot, etc...

A script could for example (see further my *shell connector* demo).

**1.**  Open DB, SSH connection and log file **simultaneously** as *[file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)*.
**2.**  Create *SQL (temporary or not) table*
**3.**  Doing loops, checking for events on DB, SSH connections or other things...
**4.**  Interact with DB and/or SSH...
**5.**  Close all *[file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)* (DB, SSH, log file, etc)

#### Mandelbrot sample:

Comments on [Mecki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749612/1765658) show a good sample of how [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) could be used to deal with other binaries (`bc` for Mandelbrot)...

Where [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) is used to *run* `bc` and aggregate its answers.

- If a script does one fork for each calculation, this script will take **many hours** to draw a Mandelbrot on an 80 column terminal.
- 1st improvement: running only one *background* fork to `bc -l` to submit all calculations drops execution time down to **8 minutes**.
- [2nd improvement:](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mandelbrot_backgndBc.sh.txt) passing *iterate* loop (up to 2000 tests) to `bc`, drops execution time down to **8 seconds**.
- [3nd improvement:](https://gist.github.com/leagris/59e1b7e72462024b278652696f375e71) creating more *background `bc`* for computing many dots simultaneously ([parallel-processing](/questions/tagged/parallel-processing)), in order to use multi-core, dividing execution time approximately by available cores... (Thanks to [Léa Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7939871/l%C3%A9a-gris) for contributing, helping making this [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) compatible, multi-core idea and adding colors, making this near beautiful, I can't resist to post their result)
  [image: Colored Mandelbrot in terminal]

### More examples

I wrote some scripts showing this powerful parallelization capabilities:

- [grepLogByDate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41831934/1765658) Where parsing log file against time stamp could become **up to 3 time quicker** using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (with at least 5 forks to `sed`, `date`, `bc` and `paste`), than using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).
- [multiping.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/multiping.sh.txt) will run many `ping` simultaneously and draw a dynamic graphic using `gnuplot`, while staying interactive.
- [shell_connector.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh.txt) is a library if *sourced* but contain a full demo using `sqlite`, `date` and `bc` as *background* co-process if *run*.
- [getSo.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223204/1765658) is a script intented to connect on SO server, by using [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl) with authentication, cookies and *Connection: keep-alive*.

In order to do some monitoring, checks against differences or so one, we could create a script to open many simultaneous connections
to many differents targets, using one of `netcat`, `sql-client`, `ftp`, `open-ssl s_client`, `ssh` or else...

... with the ability of running `sha1sum`, `grep`, `xmlint` or `bc` (if not already backgrounded) when required, while connections stays open...

### Conclusion

[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) is a super-language, useful to aggregate a complex application using many programs in various languages.

Comment: Impressive to see that you edit your answers many years after you posted them.

Comment: @kvantour I posted this answer first on `May 12 2021`. But you're right: I just <s>edited</s> rewritten [this answer to *How to test if a variable is a number*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835747/1765658) I've posted more than one year ago.

Comment: Ah, I misread the date, I thought it was May 2012 ;-) (3yrs before the actual question appeared)