# Triple input redirection symbol in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, calculator, bc

I saw a code like this that could be run on the bash prompt:  `bc fibonacci.bc <<< "fibonacci(1)"`
A function `fibonacci(n)`is defined in the file fibonacci.bc. The syntax of the function follows `bc` syntax rules.
The redirection symbol `<<<` looks new to me. Can somebody throw some light on it?

Comment: Reading your question, I think you may be interested by reading [This answer to *Is bash a programming language?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67498861/1765658)

Comment: Do a _man bash_ and search for `<<<`. The first hit will be a small section titled _Here Strings_ which explains everything about this operator.

Answer (score 2):

The `<<<` symbol is used to pass a string as the standard input of the command used.

It's called a *here-string*.

The simplest example is with `cat`:

```
cat <<< 'hello'
```

You can find a first explanation in the man bash page https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings

Comment: I would generally be hesitant to link to the ABS.

Comment: ok i edit the link by link to online bash man page

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/ might be a better link, it has HTML sections you can link to.

Comment: thank you for your feedback i edit the link with https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings