# How do I run a grep command for each line in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, grep

I have a file called **adrese.csv** that contains the first lines from another file called **rezultate2.txt**. For example:

```
www.afahc.ro/ro/rcic/simpozion/Simpozion_13/first_call.html    
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/bric/mars_bric_2008/corespondente.html
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/bric/mars_bric_2011/corespondente.html
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/bric/mars_bric_2015/corespondente.html
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/bric/mars_bric_2017/corespondente.html
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/erasmus/parteneriate.html   
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/studenti/ccoc/1/obiective.html
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/studenti/ccoc/2/servicii.html
www.anmb.ro/ro/files/studenti/ccoc/3/aspecte.html
```

The file **rezultate2.txt** contains beside these first lines a batch of text that has the word ”*abandon*” in it. I need to run `grep -E -o ".{0,50}abandon.{0,50}"` on **rezultate2.txt** for each line starting with the string in **adrese.csv** and output everything to a file, preferably a CSV. I tried different commands but nothing worked.

Sample **rezultate2.txt**

> *2345678abcd www.utm.ro/proiecte-europene/despre-pos-dru/index.html-
>
>   www.utm.ro/proiecte-europene/despre-pos-dru/index.html:Axa prioritară 2 finanţează activităţi care
>   urmăresc facilitarea tranziţiei de la şcoală la viaţa activă prin
>   dezvoltarea de programe integrate de orientare şi consiliere în
>   carieră şi prin sprijinirea parteneriatelor între şcoli, universităţi
>   şi întreprinderi; prevenirea şi corectarea fenomenului de părăsire
>   timpurie a şcolii prin programe integrate pentru prevenirea
>   abandonului şcolar, încurajarea participării şcolare şi reintegrarea
>   celor care au părăsit şcoala timpuriu; creşterea accesului şi
>   participării la formare profesională continuă prin diversificarea
>   programelor de formare profesională continuă şi sprijinirea
>   participării angajaţilor la astfel de programe.*
>
> www.utm.ro/proiecte-europene/despre-pos-dru/index.html-
>
> **Axa Prioritară 3 “Creşterea
>   adaptabilităţii lucrătorilor şi a
>   întreprinderilor”**
>
> 12345678abcd
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699.1-        
>  www.utm.ro/posdru141699.1:        Axa
>   prioritară 2 finanţează activităţi care urmăresc facilitarea
>   tranziţiei de la şcoală la viaţa activă prin dezvoltarea de programe
>   integrate de orientare şi consiliere în carieră şi prin sprijinirea
>   parteneriatelor între şcoli, universităţi şi întreprinderi, prevenirea
>   şi corectarea fenomenului de părăsire timpurie a şcolii prin programe
>   integrate pentru prevenirea abandonului şcolar, încurajarea
>   participării şcolare şi reintegrarea celor care au părăsit şcoala
>   timpuriu, creşterea accesului şi participării la  formare profesională
>   continuă prin diversificarea programelor de formare profesională
>   continuă şi sprijinirea participării angajaţilor la astfel de
>   programe. www.utm.ro/posdru141699.1-   12345678abcd
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699/index.html-       
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699/index.html:       Axa prioritară 2 finanţează
>   activităţi care urmăresc facilitarea tranziţiei de la şcoală la viaţa
>   activă prin dezvoltarea de programe integrate de orientare şi
>   consiliere în carieră şi prin sprijinirea parteneriatelor între şcoli,
>   universităţi şi întreprinderi, prevenirea şi corectarea fenomenului de
>   părăsire timpurie a şcolii prin programe integrate pentru prevenirea
>   abandonului şcolar, încurajarea participării şcolare şi reintegrarea
>   celor care au părăsit şcoala timpuriu, creşterea accesului şi
>   participării la  formare profesională continuă prin diversificarea
>   programelor de formare profesională continuă şi sprijinirea
>   participării angajaţilor la astfel de programe.
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699/index.html-    12345678abcd
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699/Despre_POSDRU.html-       
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699/Despre_POSDRU.html:       Axa prioritară 2
>   finanţează activităţi care urmăresc facilitarea tranziţiei de la
>   şcoală la viaţa activă prin dezvoltarea de programe integrate de
>   orientare şi consiliere în carieră şi prin sprijinirea parteneriatelor
>   între şcoli, universităţi şi întreprinderi, prevenirea şi corectarea
>   fenomenului de părăsire timpurie a şcolii prin programe integrate
>   pentru prevenirea abandonului şcolar, încurajarea participării şcolare
>   şi reintegrarea celor care au părăsit şcoala timpuriu, creşterea
>   accesului şi participării la  formare profesională continuă prin
>   diversificarea programelor de formare profesională continuă şi
>   sprijinirea participării angajaţilor la astfel de programe.
>   www.utm.ro/posdru141699/Despre_POSDRU.html-    12345678abcd
>   www.utm.ro/en/proiecte-europene/despre-pos-dru/index.html-
>   www.utm.ro/en/proiecte-europene/despre-pos-dru/index.html:Axa prioritară 2 finanţează activităţi care
>   urmăresc facilitarea tranziţiei de la şcoală la viaţa activă prin
>   dezvoltarea de programe integrate de orientare şi consiliere în
>   carieră şi prin sprijinirea parteneriatelor între şcoli, universităţi
>   şi întreprinderi; prevenirea şi corectarea fenomenului de părăsire
>   timpurie a şcolii prin programe integrate pentru prevenirea
>   abandonului şcolar, încurajarea participării şcolare şi reintegrarea
>   celor care au părăsit şcoala timpuriu; creşterea accesului şi
>   participării la formare profesională continuă prin diversificarea
>   programelor de formare profesională continuă şi sprijinirea
>   participării angajaţilor la astfel de programe.
>   www.utm.ro/en/proiecte-europene/despre-pos-dru/index.html-
>
> **Axa Prioritară 3 “Creşterea
>   adaptabilităţii lucrătorilor şi a
>   întreprinderilor”**

Desired output is a file containing the line in **adrese.csv** and it's corresponding text with just the word "abandon" and the 50 chars to the left and right of it:

www.utgjiu.ro/despre/index.html?p=5400 *în timp ce vechi așezări se depopulează și cad în **abandon**. Nevoia unor sisteme de referință este, poate, ma*

---

Managed to get what I needed with the help of a friend. The Python script below was written by Radu Eosif Mihăilescu:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""Custom work for Razvan T. Coloja, placed in the public domain by the author.
"""

import sys

MAGIC_WORD = 'abandon'

def main(argv):
    with open(argv[1], 'r') as faddr:
        addresses = set(l.rstrip() for l in faddr)
    with open(argv[2], 'r') as fres:
        the_text = set(l.rstrip() for l in fres)

    for address in addresses:
        for line in the_text:
            if line.startswith(address):
                where_found = line.find(MAGIC_WORD)
                if where_found != -1:
                    if where_found > 50:
                        start_excerpt = where_found - 50
                    else:
                        start_excerpt = 0
                    print '"%s","%s"' % (
                        address,
                        line[start_excerpt:where_found + len(MAGIC_WORD) + 50])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939038/how-do-you-run-a-command-for-each-line-of-a-file

It might help you .

Comment: How about showing sample data for BOTH files, and the desired output? So far it's mostly guesswork for others.

Comment: Sample data:

**rezultate2.txt**

`code`www.uvvg.ro/site/un-askenaz-intre-romania-si-eritreea/index.html-<p><strong>Eritreea</strong> (oficial <strong>Statul Eritreea</strong>) este un situat în partea de <strong>nord-est a Africii</strong>, mărginit de Sudan la nord și nord-vest, Etiopia la sud și vest, Djibouti la sud-est și Marea Roșie la est. <strong>Fostă colonie italiană și britanică</strong>, Eritreea a fost <strong>anexată de Etiopia în 1952</strong>

`code`

Comment: The comment section doesn't allow me to write too many characters. The desired output would be the first line in adrese.csv followed by the corresponding grep ouput above (the word "abandon" and the 50 characters left and right of it).

Comment: Just edit your original post ...

Comment: Update your question with the relevant information rather than adding it in comments.

Comment: Heh. And now edit the edit so it's actually readable ;D

Comment: What you're asking for is, taken at face value, both insanely inefficient and utterly unnecessary. `grep` can take a list of patterns to use as input, so you can find all lines in file2 matching any line from file1 in just one pass. And if you want to do an efficient join, there are likewise join tools written just for the purpose that do a single pass through two sorted inputs, finding lines in common.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right what you are trying to achieve (running a `grep` on `adrese.csv` for each line with "abandon" in `rezultate2.txt`) the following snippet should do just that:

```
grep -E -o ".{0,50}abandon.{0,50}" rezultate2.txt | while read LINE ; do
  grep "$LINE" adrese.csv >> output.csv
done
```

Comment: That would seem right. Thank you. But the script gives me the following error:

`grep: Unmatched [ or [^
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
grep: invalid option -- '&'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '&'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.`

and output.csv is just about 10 lines long while adrese.csv is about 650+ lines long.

Comment: Probably `rezultate2.txt` contains characters that are interpreted as regexp - if you do not want that use `-F` switch:
`grep -F "$LINE" adrese.csv >> output.csv`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot about -F. The thing is i still get the same error, even with -F:

`cypress@aspire:~/Desktop$ sh script_final.sh 
grep: invalid option -- '&'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid option -- '&'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.`

Comment: @RazvanT.Coloja, sounds like you have a line that starts with a dash. Use `-e` before it, thus: `grep -F -e "$LINE"`. (Though I stand by my comment on the question that given an explanation of *why* you're trying to do this -- and thus what constraints you have, regarding ordering or otherwise -- we could come up with a vastly more efficient alternative).

Comment: Tried it. No error this time but the resulting **output.csv** is still small. I think I will run **html2txt** on **rezultate2.txt** to clean it up a bit. But thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, this:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' adrese.csv | while read text ; do grep -F "$text" rezultate2.txt ; done > output.txt
```

Will:

1. The sed will convert the csv file into single lines
2. The while loop will take each of those inputs
3. And grep through the file for them.
4. Each of the output will be saved into output.txt