# how to continue with the loop even though we use exit for a condition in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a following list.txt file with the content

```
cat list.txt
one
two
zero
three
four
```

I have a shell script (check.sh) like below,

```
for i in $(cat list.txt)
do
if [ $i != zero ]; then
echo "the number is $i"
else
exit 1
fi
done
```

it gives output like below,

```
./check.sh
the number is one
the number is two
```

I want to have script which continue with the rest of the items in the list.txt, but it should not process zero and continue with the rest of item.
eg.

```
the number is one
the number is two
the number is three
the number is four
```

I tried using "return" but it did not work, gave error.

```
./check.sh: line 6: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

Comment: You don't need `else; exit 1`, simply drop this two lines!

Comment: And yes, please, consider [accepting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if your question is answered! [(On all your already asked questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14762667/anandan-ramar?tab=questions)

Answer (score 3):

#### About `exit` (and `return`)

The command `exit` will **quit** running script. There is no way to *continue*.

As well, `return` command will **quit** function. There in no more way to *continue*.

#### About reading input file

For processing line based input file, you'd better to use `while read` instead of  `for i in $(cat...`:

Simply try:

```
while read -r i;do
    if [ "$i" != "zero" ] ;then
        echo number $i
    fi
done <list.txt
```

#### Alternatively, you could drop unwanted entries **before** loop:

```
while read -r i;do
    echo number $i
done < <( grep -v ^zero$ <list.txt)
```

Note: In this specific case, `^zero$` don't need to be quoted. Consider quoting if your string do contain special characters or spaces.

If you have more than one entries to drop, you could use

```
while read -r i;do echo number $i ;done < <(grep -v '^\(zero\|null\)$' <list.txt)
```

#### Alternatively, once input file filtered, use `xargs`:

If your process is only one single command, you could avoid [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) loop by using `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 1 echo number < <(grep -v '^\(zero\|null\)$' <list.txt)
```

#### How to use `continue` in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script

Maybe you are thinking about something like:

```
while read -r i;do
    if [ "$i" = "zero" ] ;then
        continue
    fi
    echo number $i
done <list.txt
```

Argument of `continue` is a number representing number of loop to shortcut.

Try this:

```
for i in {1..5};do
    for l in {a..d};do
        if [ "$i" -eq 3 ] && [ "$l" = "b" ] ;then
            continue 2
        fi
        echo $i.$l
    done
done
```

(This print `3.a` and stop `3` serie at `3.b`, breaking 2 loop level)

Then compare with

```
for i in {1..5};do
    for l in {a..d};do
        if [ "$i" -eq 3 ] && [ "$l" = "b" ] ;then
            continue 1
        fi
        echo $i.$l
    done
done
```

(This print `3.a` , `3.c` and `3.d`. Only `3.b` are skipped, breaking only 1 loop level)

Comment: @JamesBrown Added some sample of `continue` uses.

Comment: For more infos, you could have a look at: [How do you run a command for each line of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941223/1765658)