# Remove file if a file with the same name but different extension doesn't exist in another directory

Tags: bash

I have 3 directories. I want to delete the files in `raw` and `xml` which **are not in** `clean_raw`.

```
sample
.
├── clean_raw
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   └── 5.jpg
├── raw
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   ├── 3.jpg
│   ├── 4.jpg
│   └── 5.jpg
└── xml
    ├── 1.xml
    ├── 2.xml
    ├── 3.xml
    ├── 4.xml
    └── 5.xml
```

I used rsync to delete the same file names from `raw` directory using the below line.

```
rsync -r --delete --existing --ignore-existing sample/clean_raw/ sample/raw/
```

This deletes the images `3.jpg`, `4.jpg` from `raw` directory.

How to delete the file xmls from  `3.xml`, `4.xml` using shell script?

Comment: Do you care if the file contents are different? Or just that they have the same name?

Comment: Create a directory `xmlnew`. Loop through the files in `raw`, and for each `X.jpg` do a `mv xml/X.xml xmlnew`. If you are done, do a `rm -r xml; mv xmlnew xml`.

Comment: @jhnc The contents are different in all the folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
for xml in sample/xml/*; do
  jpg=${xml%.*}.jpg
  jpg=${xml%/*/*}/clean_raw/${jpg##*/}
  if ! test -f "$jpg"; then
    echo rm "$xml"
  fi
done
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 2):

### Re-use `rsync` output:

Doing so will ensure `rm` is done along `rsyc` process and avoid the need of browsing directories, searching for inexistant files.

#### Using ***pure*** [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
while read -r action file;do
    [ "$action" = "deleting" ] &&
        [ -f "sample/xml/${file%.*}.xml" ] &&
        rm -v "sample/xml/${file%.*}.xml"
done < <(
    rsync -vr --delete --existing --ignore-existing \
        sample/clean_raw/ sample/raw/
)
```

may produce:

```
removed 'sample/xml/5.xml'
removed 'sample/xml/4.xml'
```

Then you could remove `-v` option in `rm` to suppress this output.

##### Further sample

Building an array containing list of `.xml` files to delete. This permit to run `rm` command one time for deleting all files simultaneously.

This sample will list and prompt user before deletion.

```
rsyncCmd=(rsync -vr --delete --existing --ignore-existing)
source=sample/clean_raw
target=sample/raw
xmlFiles=()
while read -r action file;do
    [ "$action" = "deleting" ] &&
        [ -f "sample/xml/${file%.*}.xml" ] &&
        xmlFiles+=("sample/xml/${file%.*}.xml")
done < <(
    "${rsyncCmd[@]}" "$source/" "$target/"
)
if [ -f "${xmlFiles[0]}" ] ;then
    ls -l "${xmlFiles[@]}"
    read -sn 1 -p "Delete ${#xmlFiles[@]} files (Y/n)? " answer
    case "$answer" in
        n|N )   echo No  ;;
        *   )   echo Yes;
                rm -v "${xmlFiles[@]}";;
    esac
fi
```

#### By using `sed`

Use `-v` (verbose) switch to `rsync` command, then trap lines in form *`deleting file.jpg`* with `sed` to create on-the-fly a shell script for removing `.xml` files.

```
rsync -vr --delete --existing --ignore-existing sample/clean_raw/ sample/raw/ |
    sed -ne 's/^deleting \(.*\).jpg/rm -v \o47sample\/xml\/\1.xml\o47/p' |
    sh
```

#### By using `sed`, but keeping *rsync's logfile*.

If for any reason, even debugging, you would store `rsync` logfile, while executing `sed '...rm ..'|sh`, you could use `tee` for this:

```
rsync -vr --delete --existing --ignore-existing sample/clean_raw/ sample/raw/ |
    tee /path/to/rsynclog.txt |
    sed -ne 's/^deleting \(.*\).jpg/rm -v \o47sample\/xml\/\1.xml\o47/p' |
    sh
```

You could add `-a` option to `tee` command for *appending* output to existing log file instead of overwriting existing log file if exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read fil
do
   if test ! -f "<path to clean_raw>/$fil"
   then 
       echo "rm -f "<path to xml>/$fil"
       #rm -f "<path to xml>/$fil"
   fi
done <<< (find <path to xml> -name "*.jpg -printf "%f\n")
```

Use find to attain a list of files in the xml folder and print just the file names with printf. Redirect this into a while loop, that takes each file and checks if it exists in clean_raw. If it doesn't delete the file

Repeat the step for the raw folder

Echo has been used to check that files list as expected. Comment out the echo command and uncomment in rm when you are happy.

Comment: What an ugly inline string redirection for inline command!  Why not `done < <(find ...`... And: `While` so capitalized is not a command.