# executing find command with a file having directory list

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a big file which contains directories paths like below:

```
$PRJ/fp/t/mxl/lf/
$PRJ/fp/t/mxl/lf/
```

I want to read this file line by line and list out all the files inside each directory file in a line in output file.

I can use **find** command with directory path directory specify but how to use it with a file having directory paths is something I want.
`find input_file -type f`
does not work.

Comment: What if there are nested directories inside?

Comment: There are no nested directories inside. The input file have directory path which just have files inside it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run a command eg chmod, for each line of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939038/how-do-you-run-a-command-eg-chmod-for-each-line-of-a-file)

Comment: You have to use something like `xargs -I {} find {} -type f <bigfile`. See [my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941223/1765658)

Comment: Please don't multi-post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/712147/133219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    find "$dir" -type f
done < <(envsubst < my_big_file)
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294400/133219 and the man page for more info on `envsubst`.

Comment: Interesting solution. I believe `$PRJ_WORK_DIR` should be set as an environmental variable for this to work. If that's not the case, `eval` is other more dangerous alternative.