# Bash - Redirecting Stderr To File Redirects Stdin

Tags: linux, bash

I want to read input (and show input prompt) from Terminal in my Bash script and redirect Stderr and Stdout to the same file. I am running my script called `test.sh` like this:

```
./test.sh &> logs
```

Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter 1 or 0 " var

echo "hello"

bash <<EOF >> logs
    echo "testing"
    error
EOF
```

However, since it is redirecting Stdin to file, I do not get this prompt ("Enter 1 or 0 ") on Terminal as I am hoping to get. How can I redirect Stderr & Stdout to file but receive Stdin from Terminal? Thanks.

Comment: `read -p` use same *redirected* output!  You have to force `read` to use *`TTY`*  for output his prompt! Try:  `read -p .... >/dev/tty`

Comment: At [Read a file line by line and execute commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941223/1765658), read quietly chapter **`4. while read, using dedicated fd.`** and his `4.2` [bash] version...